# Iterm2 Color Configuration

Tags: iterm

Can anyone assist me how to achieve this kind of color scheme?

The color of the directory, commands, etc are all different which I really like. Please assist. I'm using a Mac OS X El Capitan - iTerm.

[image: Desired Look]

Answer (score 0):

Some modern shells come with fancy themes you can customize to your convenience, a couple for you:

- https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh
- http://fishshell.com/ (excellent web tool to customize the appearance but non-standard bash).